# Image saving to wrong file path

Tags: python, save, python-imaging-library

I've made a program to create an image from an array. In the end, I convert it using PIL's .fromarray() and then save it using the .save() method. I don't specify a file path as I want to save the file in the same path as the program is in. Instead of doing that, my image gets saved in a completely different unrelated path. How do I get it to save the image in the same path as the program without specifying the file path?

The program is in the path: "C:\Users\Bloo\Desktop\extra\skins\skin maker"

The image gets saved to the path: "C:\Users\Bloo\Desktop\Homework\Computer Science"

This is the saving bit of my code.

```
# convert the array to an image
image = Image.fromarray(colorData)

# ask for the file name
fileName = input("Please enter the file name you would like for the skin image. Format is not required\n")
fileName += ".png"    # add the file format to end of file name

# save the image
image.save(fileName, "PNG")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the beginning of you file:

```py
import os

program_directory_name = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.chdir(program_directory_name)
```

Then your working directory would be the same as directory of file you run.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not specifying a path and it saves the file in a different directory, then your working directory is probably different then your file path.

Check your working directory :

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

You can change the working directory like this:

```
os.chdir('directory')
```

Combine that with `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` which returns the absolute path of your file to change your working directory to the file directory:

```
filedir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.chdir(filedir)
```

You can then check for the working directory to confirm it changed and is now matching the file directory.

Comment: You should describe what to do in case the output of os.getcwd() is not as expected.

Comment: Updated with description.